# Laravel - Getting errors when using HTTPS and AJAX only on Safari and a few other browsers

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

When I'm doing a post request using AJAX, I'm getting this error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '/*' (T_STRING), expecting
>   ')' in /home/laravel/public_html/public/index.php on line 47
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/user/public_html/vendor/ClassLoader.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/user/public_html/vendor/autoload.php on line 6

The index.php it's referring to is as following:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I have no idea why this is happening.

This only happens in safari and a few other browsers. Doesn't happen on chrome.

The inspect element looks like this:
[image: Error on Web Developer Tools]

Please help guys. Thanks

Edit: Folder structure:

```
home/user/laravel -> All my laravel files
home/user/laravel/public_html/public -> my public folder
```

When I do `composer install`, it gives me this error:

```
Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /usr/bin
```

For some reason, it's looking for composer.json file in /usr/bin. The composer.json file is in the current directory in which I am cd'd to.

Comment: Is public folder in laravel root folder?

Comment: I updated my thread with the folder structure. Basically it's this `home/user/laravel -> All my laravel files &
home/user/laravel/public_html/public -> my public folder `

Comment: Taylor Swift knows php..?

Comment: You have to run composer install from home/user/laravel folder. Witch index php is the posted one (home/user/laravel, or home/user/laravel/public_html/public)?

Comment: home/user/laravel/public_html is the one that's posted. And I'm running composer install from the same directory you're talking about, and I'm getting the same error. `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.16
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /usr/bin`

Comment: I think you have a conflict between home/user/laravel/public_html/public/index.php and home/user/laravel/public/index.php.

Comment: I only have one public directory, and it's at public_html/public/index.php.

Comment: Add this in your index.php to set the public path to this directory. $app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return __DIR__;
    });  After $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php'; see if it works.

Comment: I added that, still no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98580/discussion-between-mirceac21-and-taylor-swift).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: index.php should look like this:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

That will hopefully do the trick.

The first line of any PHP file should be

```
<?php
```

Somehow that's missing in your copy of the index file. I'm not sure how that happened, but that would be the error you're seeing.

Comment: Which laravel version is this?

Comment: Also it looks like your folder structure may be to blame, what does `ls -l /home/user/public_html` return?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Dec 20 22:44 cgi-bin  .........
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   13 Dec 21 03:15 offline.html .........
drwxr-xr-x 6 user user 4096 Dec 21 01:46 public` ........

Comment: Is there another folder called laravel under /home/user/laravel, because that's what those requires are looking for.

Comment: Nope. There are the only files home/user/laravel `a.out,    bootstrap,      config,       pm-debug.log,  phpunit.xml,  server.php,  vendor,
app,      composer.json,  database,     package.json,   readme.md,    storage, artisan,  composer.lock,  gulpfile.js,  phpspec.yml,    resources,    tests`. The public folder is over in the public_html directory

Comment: I tried that, but still having the same issue. I had to change the path otherwise the directory wouldn't exist. So basically it would be the same thing that I had earlier

Comment: I would recommend against changing the directory structure of a framework like laravel anyway. If the issue is service static HTML pages that are then populated with AJAX, there are easier ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Exact same. It was happening only on HTTPS.

Here's what I did:

First thing's first. Run these commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear 

chmod -R 777 app/storage 

composer dump-autoload

php artisan optimize
```

Then run

```
npm install
```

Make sure that in your public_html folder, there is no `index.html` or `index.php` file. It should only be in the `public_html/public` folder.

After that, ensure that you Htaccess is set up properly.

Htaccess in `public_html` directory should be something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

After doing the following, let me know how it goes. Also, be sure to look at the log file in storage/logs/laravel.log and your Apache logs.

Cheers!